# Issues with errant updates from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The issue we are seeing revolves around the stored procedure I have added below. The goal of the procedure is to extract data from table A (budCreditCardTrans) and insert into table B (bAPHB). In addition, for each row, we are making copies of its related rows in Table C (HQAT).

All of these tasks are working fine and are processing correct. However, we have one edge case that is causing up significant issue. The last step of the cursor's body is to go back to Table A and update the Rows processed flag to Y to indicate the row has went through this process.

The issue we are seeing is that randomly, the last row processed is overwriting one of the other rows in the set and setting most of the columns to NULL. This happens once in every 50 runs or so. In addition to that, our audit logs are implying that a user who doesn't have access to the table to run the procedure is credit with the edit.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Some of the things we have already attempted:

1. Most of our attempts have been application side trying to figure out the workflow that is causing these issues. We have found that ensuring on our application that you don't have two windows open will keep the issue from being more expansive.

```
budCreditCardTrans


+-------+----+---------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-------------+
| KeyID | Co | idMatchNumber | AccountNumber |            UniqueAttchID             | processed | BatchID | BatchMth | ready | transactionDate |    CardNumber    | EmployeeCo | EmployeeRef |
+-------+----+---------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-------------+
|     1 |  2 | 123AAA        | XXX           | 205f2df7-6ef9-485e-bf48-5c6e94ede3c2 | N         |       1 |        4 | Y     | 2019-08-08      | 1111111111111111 |          2 |         323 |
|     2 |  2 | 123BBB        | XXX           | 205f2df7-6ef9-485e-bf48-5c6e94ededdd | N         |       1 |        4 | Y     | 2019-08-09      | 2222222222222222 |          2 |         323 |
|     3 |  2 | 123CCC        | XXX           | 205f2df7-6ef9-485e-bf48-5c6e94edefff | N         |       1 |        4 | Y     | 2019-08-10      | 3333333333333333 |          2 |         323 |
+-------+----+---------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-------------+
HQAT

+------+----------+---------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------+
| HQCo | FormName |               KeyField                | Description | AttachmentID (PK) | TableName |            UniqueAttchID             | KeyID |
+------+----------+---------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------+
|    2 | fARCM    | ARCM.CustGroup = 1 AND Customer=428   | Test        |                 1 | ARCM      | B2AE77A5-5402-4E76-9CF3-373B89B1B080 |     1 |
|    2 | fJCCM    | JCCM.JCCo = 1 AND Contract=1111111-11 | Tes1        |                 2 | JCCM      | B2AE77A5-5402-4E76-9CF3-373B89B1Baaa |     2 |
|    2 | fJCJM    | JCJM.JCCo = 1 AND Job=1111111-12      | Test2       |                 3 | JCJM      | B2AE77A5-5402-4E76-9CF3-373B89B1Bbbb |     3 |
+------+----------+---------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------+

bAPHB

+----+-----+---------+----------+----------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+----------+---------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| Co | Mth | BatchId | BatchSeq | BatchTransType | VendorGroup | Vendor |   APRef    |  InvDate   | InvTotal | udCreditCardHolderCompany | udCreditCardHolder | udCreditCardTrans |            UniqueAttchID             | udMerchantName | Notes  |   udCreditCardComplianceNotes   |
+----+-----+---------+----------+----------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+----------+---------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  2 |   4 |       1 |        1 | A              |           1 |     74 | MDOAK39656 | 2019-08-08 |   100.00 | Test Company              | John Smith         |         123456789 | B7DE50EB-00F9-4F80-A456-039EA53D637A | Johns Pizza    | Test   | Notes from budCreditCardTrans   |
|  2 |   4 |       1 |        2 | A              |           1 |     74 | MDOAK39657 | 2019-08-09 |   200.00 | Test Company              | John Smith         |         123456790 | B7DE50EB-00F9-4F80-A456-039EA53D6AAA | Kims Tool Shop | Test 2 | Notes from budCreditCardTrans 2 |
|  2 |   4 |       1 |        3 | A              |           1 |     74 | MDOAK39658 | 2019-08-10 |   325.00 | Test Company              | John Smith         |         123456791 | B7DE50EB-00F9-4F80-A456-039EA53D6BBB | Sheetz         | Test 3 | Notes from budCreditCardTrans 3 |
+----+-----+---------+----------+----------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+----------+---------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

```
USE [Viewpoint]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspAPCreditCardTransInsert_AMG2]    Script Date: 9/11/2019 4:04:38 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspAPCreditCardTransInsert_AMG2]

    @APCo bCompany = null,
    @Mth bMonth = null,
    @BatchId bBatchID = null
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NEW_ATTACHMENT_ID uniqueidentifier;
    DECLARE @CURRENT_ATTACHMENT_ID uniqueidentifier;

    DECLARE 
        @TransCo TinyInt,
        @TransMth SmallDateTime,
        @TransBatchId Int,
        @BatchSeq Int,
        @BatchTransType Char(1),
        @VendorGroup TinyInt,
        @Vendor Int,
        @APRef VarChar(15),
        @InvDate SmallDateTime,
        @DueDate SmallDateTime,
        @InvTotal Numeric(12,2),
        @udCreditCardHolderCompany TinyInt,
        @udCreditCardHolder Int,
        @udCreditCardTrans VarChar(30),
        @CMCo TinyInt,
        @CMAcct Smallint,
        @PayMethod Char(1),
        @UniqueAttchID uniqueidentifier,
        @PrePaidYN Char(1),
        @V1099YN Char(1),
        @PayOverrideYN Char(1),
        @MerchantName Char(50),
        @Notes varchar(1000),
        @ComplianceNotes varchar(1000)

    DECLARE @MessageOutput VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @ATTACH_ID Int;

    DECLARE Transaction_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
          @APCo AS Co,
          @Mth AS Mth,
          @BatchId AS BatchId,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Cards.EmployeeCo, Cards.EmployeeRef, budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) AS BatchSeq,
          'A' AS BatchTransType,
          @APCo AS VendorGroup,
          Cards.VendorNo AS Vendor,
         /*Build out AP Reference number based on the statement month of the transaction*/
          CASE 
                /* Beitzel transactions from Comdata*/
                WHEN Cards.Co = 1 AND Cards.VendorNo = 5613 THEN    
                    LEFT(CONVERT(char(8), budCreditCardTrans.postedDate, 1),2)
                    + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) as VarChar), 2) 
                    + '-'
                    + CAST(Cards.EmployeeRef as varchar) 
                    + '-' 
                    + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 5)

                /* Pillar transactions from Comdata*/
                WHEN Cards.Co = 2 AND Cards.VendorNo = 3517 THEN    
                    LEFT(CONVERT(char(8), budCreditCardTrans.postedDate, 1),2)
                    + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) as VarChar), 2) 
                    + '-'
                    + CAST(Cards.EmployeeRef as varchar) 
                    + '-' 
                    + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 5)           

                /* Beitzel transactions from BOA w/ posted dates in current statement month*/
                WHEN Cards.Co = 1 AND Cards.VendorNo = 3200 AND DAY(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) < 28 THEN    
                    LEFT(CONVERT(char(8), budCreditCardTrans.postedDate, 1),2)
                    + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) as VarChar), 2) 
                    + '-'
                    + CAST(Cards.EmployeeRef as varchar) 
                    + '-' 
                    + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 5)

                /* Pillar transactions from BOA w/ posted dates in current statement month*/
                WHEN Cards.Co = 2 AND Cards.VendorNo = 393 AND DAY(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) < 28 THEN 
                    LEFT(CONVERT(char(8), budCreditCardTrans.postedDate, 1),2)
                    + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) as VarChar), 2) 
                    + '-'
                    + CAST(Cards.EmployeeRef as varchar) 
                    + '-' 
                    + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 5)

                /* Beitzel transactions from BOA which posted on the following statement cycle - DOES NOT CONSIDER YEAR CHANGES*/
                WHEN Cards.Co = 1 AND Cards.VendorNo = 3200 AND DAY(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) >= 28 THEN   
                    LEFT(CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(MM,1,budCreditCardTrans.postedDate), 1),2)
                    + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) as VarChar), 2) 
                    + '-'
                    + CAST(Cards.EmployeeRef as varchar) 
                    + '-' 
                    + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 5)

                /* Pillar transactions from BOA which posted on the following statement cycle - DOES NOT CONSIDER YEAR CHANGES*/
                WHEN Cards.Co = 2 AND Cards.VendorNo = 393 AND DAY(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) >= 28 THEN    
                    LEFT(CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(MM,1,budCreditCardTrans.postedDate), 1),2)
                    + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) as VarChar), 2) 
                    + '-'
                    + CAST(Cards.EmployeeRef as varchar) 
                    + '-' 
                    + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 5)

          END AS APRef,

          budCreditCardTrans.transactionDate AS InvDate,
          DATEFROMPARTS(
            CASE WHEN MONTH(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate)=12 THEN YEAR(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate)+1 ELSE YEAR(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate) END,
            CASE WHEN MONTH(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate)=12 THEN 1 ELSE MONTH(budCreditCardTrans.postedDate)+1 END,
            7) AS DueDate,
          budCreditCardTrans.postedAmount AS InvTotal,
          Cards.EmployeeCo AS udCreditCardHolderCompany,
          Cards.EmployeeRef AS udCreditCardHolder,
          budCreditCardTrans.id AS udCreditCardTrans,
          @APCo AS CMCo,
          CASE WHEN @APCo = 1 THEN 5474 ELSE 4339 END AS CMAcct,
          'C' AS PayMethod,
          budCreditCardTrans.UniqueAttchID,
          'N' AS PrepaidYN,
          'N' AS V1099YN,
          'N' AS PayOverrideYN,
          budCreditCardTrans.merchantName AS MerchantName,
          budCreditCardTrans.udNotes AS Notes,
          budCreditCardTrans.ComplianceNotes AS ComplianceNotes
        FROM
          budCreditCardTrans
          LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    budCreditCards.Co,
                    REPLACE(budCreditCards.AccountNumber,' ','') AS CardNumberTrimmed,
                    budCreditCards.EmployeeCo,
                    budCreditCards.EmployeeRef,
                    budCreditCards.VendorNo
                FROM
                    budCreditCards
                GROUP BY
                    budCreditCards.Co,
                    REPLACE(budCreditCards.AccountNumber,' ',''),
                    budCreditCards.EmployeeCo,
                    budCreditCards.EmployeeRef,
                    budCreditCards.VendorNo
                    )Cards

                ON Cards.Co = budCreditCardTrans.Co AND Cards.CardNumberTrimmed = budCreditCardTrans.cardNumber
        WHERE
         @APCo = budCreditCardTrans.Co AND
          budCreditCardTrans.processed = 'N' AND
          budCreditCardTrans.ready = 'Y' AND
          (budCreditCardTrans.BatchReadyUser = SYSTEM_USER or budCreditCardTrans.BatchReadyUser is null)
          AND
          (YEAR(budCreditCardTrans.transactionDate) = YEAR(@Mth) AND MONTH(budCreditCardTrans.transactionDate) = Month(@Mth))



    OPEN Transaction_Cursor 

    FETCH NEXT FROM Transaction_Cursor INTO
    @TransCo,
        @TransMth,
        @TransBatchId,
        @BatchSeq,
        @BatchTransType,
        @VendorGroup,
        @Vendor,
        @APRef,
        @InvDate,
        @DueDate,
        @InvTotal,
        @udCreditCardHolderCompany,
        @udCreditCardHolder,
        @udCreditCardTrans,
        @CMCo,
        @CMAcct,
        @PayMethod,
        @UniqueAttchID,
        @PrePaidYN,
        @V1099YN,
        @PayOverrideYN,
        @MerchantName,
        @Notes,
        @ComplianceNotes



    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- WHILE WE HAVE ROWS
    BEGIN

    /**
        Duplicate Attachment ID;
        Create New ID;
        Copy Existing Attachment into Temp Table;
        Update AttachmentID in temp table
        Re-insert with new ID
        CLEAR Temp Attachment
    */
    SET @NEW_ATTACHMENT_ID = NEWID();
    SET @CURRENT_ATTACHMENT_ID = @UniqueAttchID;
    SELECT @ATTACH_ID = (MAX(AttachmentID) + 1) from bHQAT;
    SELECT * INTO #TempAttach FROM HQAT WHERE UniqueAttchID = @CURRENT_ATTACHMENT_ID;
    ALTER TABLE #TempAttach DROP COLUMN KeyID;
    UPDATE #TempAttach SET UniqueAttchID = @NEW_ATTACHMENT_ID,  TableName = 'APHB', FormName = 'APEntry', AttachmentID = @ATTACH_ID;
    INSERT INTO bHQAT SELECT * FROM #TempAttach;
    DELETE #TempAttach;
    DROP TABLE #TempAttach;
    /**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */


    INSERT INTO bAPHB
    (Co,
    Mth,
    BatchId,
    BatchSeq,
    BatchTransType,
    VendorGroup,
    Vendor,
    APRef,
    InvDate,
    DueDate,
    InvTotal,
    udCreditCardHolderCompany,
    udCreditCardHolder,
    udCreditCardTrans,
    CMCo,
    CMAcct,
    PayMethod,
    UniqueAttchID,
    PrePaidYN,
    V1099YN,
    PayOverrideYN,
    udMerchantName,
    Notes,
    udCreditCardComplianceNotes
    )
    VALUES(
        @TransCo,
        @TransMth,
        @TransBatchId,
        @BatchSeq,
        @BatchTransType,
        @VendorGroup,
        @Vendor,
        @APRef,
        @InvDate,
        @DueDate,
        @InvTotal,
        @udCreditCardHolderCompany,
        @udCreditCardHolder,
        @udCreditCardTrans,
        @CMCo,
        @CMAcct,
        @PayMethod,
        @NEW_ATTACHMENT_ID, -- @UniqueAttchID
        @PrePaidYN,
        @V1099YN,
        @PayOverrideYN,
        @MerchantName,
        @Notes,
        @ComplianceNotes
    )

    UPDATE bHQAT SET KeyField = 'KeyID=' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as Varchar) WHERE AttachmentID = @ATTACH_ID
    UPDATE budCreditCardTrans SET 
    processed = 'Y',
    BatchMonth = @Mth,
    BatchId = @BatchId
    WHERE id = @udCreditCardTrans

    RAISERROR(@MessageOutput,0,1) WITH NOWAIT

    FETCH NEXT FROM Transaction_Cursor INTO
    @TransCo,
        @TransMth,
        @TransBatchId,
        @BatchSeq,
        @BatchTransType,
        @VendorGroup,
        @Vendor,
        @APRef,
        @InvDate,
        @DueDate,
        @InvTotal,
        @udCreditCardHolderCompany,
        @udCreditCardHolder,
        @udCreditCardTrans,
        @CMCo,
        @CMAcct,
        @PayMethod,
        @UniqueAttchID,
        @PrePaidYN,
        @V1099YN,
        @PayOverrideYN,
        @MerchantName,
        @Notes,
        @ComplianceNotes
    END
    CLOSE  Transaction_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE  Transaction_Cursor



END
```

Comment: First of all...why are you doing this in a cursor? This should be a set based operation, not RBAR (row by agonizing row). But there is no chance anybody can debug this for you. This is over 300 lines of t-sql with no table definitions, sample data or desired output.

Comment: Is the SP being called concurrently? You need transaction for the change.

Comment: I suggest to change the cursor to a temp table with an identity column like id, and loop by the id. YOur last statement updates the field used by the cursor, which may cause side effect.

Comment: There are too problems with this code to even try to analyse. I just hope this code is not responsible for my credit card transactions.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you for the response. Both tables are around 50ish columns wide so I will attempt to add them in a more condensed manner with only relevant fields. Question,  I am not sure how you do a set operation across rows that get individually updated along with indepentant operations into another table (HQAT). Any advice on that would be helpful

Comment: You use FROM and JOIN in your update statement.

Comment: @Alex I don't doubt this code isn't great. I am not a DBA by trade, just a DevOps engineer. I am only assisting accounting with understanding what is going wrong. Admittedly I did put the cursor loop in there because I understand row by row better that more complex set operations

Comment: @PeterHe I will give those changes a try for sure